# Confused computing sum of Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I am having some issues understanding Fourier series and I am stuck trying to solve a problem.

So the function $u$ has period $2\pi$ and is defined as

$$u(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & 0 \leq x \lt \pi \\
      0 & \pi \leq x \lt 2\pi \\
 \end{cases},
$$
And I should determine the Fourier series and compute the sum of the series at $x = 0$ and $x = \pi$.

So I managed to compute the Fourier series so that

$$u(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{-\infty,\space n \space \mathrm{odd}}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inx}}{in\pi}.$$

But now I am wondering, first of all, the sum at $x = 0$ should, according to the book, be $\frac{1}{2},$ but in the beginning it is stated that $u(0) = 1$. Is that just the Fourier representation doing a "bad job"?

Secondly, I keep failing when I am trying to compute the sum. Beginning with $x=0$, I tried to compute

$$u(0) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{i\pi} \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1}.$$ I wrote it like that because $n$ is odd. But doesn't $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1}$ diverge?

Comment: I'm no expert on Fourier series, but I believe I remember seeing that at a point discontinuity, the series converges to the average of the limits from the left and right.

Comment: About the "bad job"... it's an integral transform. Integral doesn't see a difference if you assign a single point to a different value (setting u(0)=0 or u(0)=1 just moves a single isolated point that's less than a drop in the ocean for the transform). It only sees the big picture - a fourier series is a sum of continuous functions so if you transform a discontinuous one, you go a bit out of capabilities, and the closest you can get is, the average at the jump (in addition, it overshoots too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Comment: None of the answers seems to address your last question, whether $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}1/(2n-1)$ diverges. Indeed it does diverge according to the usual definition for doubly infinite series, where $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ means $\lim_{M \to \infty}\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-M}^{N}$. But with Fourier series, the convention is that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ means $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}$. The rationale for this is that we are really interested in the convergence of the corresponding sine and cosine series, which are obtained by combining the $N$ and $-N$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the "bad job", please refer to the Dirichlet Fourier Series Conditions (Dirichlet's Theorem). As Bungo mentioned, to address the issue of the divergence of $\sum {1\over 2n-1}$, it is best to write the series as a limit:
$$u(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}u_N(x)$$
where $$u_N(x)=\frac 12 +\frac1{i\pi}\sum_{-N,\ n \text{ odd}}^N\frac {e^{inx}}{n}$$
$$u_N(0)=\frac 12+\frac 1 {i\pi} \sum_{-N, \ n \text{ odd}}^N \frac 1n$$

$$u_N(0)=\frac 12+\frac 1 {i\pi} \left(\sum_{0}^N \frac 1{2n+1}-\sum_{0}^N \frac 1{2n+1}\right)$$
$$u_N(0)=\frac 12$$
$$u(0)=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}u_N(0)=\frac12$$

Comment: +1. I didn't notice that when I wrote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The expression$$\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1} - \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$is highly problematic as neither series converges. Indeed, $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges according to the usual convention with doubly infinite series. The only reason it converges here is that with Fourier series, the convention is that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ means $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}$ instead of the usual  $\lim_{M \to \infty}\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-M}^{N}$

Comment: @Bungo I have edited my answer as to clearly include your remark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}1dx=1$$
for $n=1,2\cdots$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos nx\, dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos nx\,dx=0$$
$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos nx\, dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin nx\,dx=\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{n\pi}$$
therefore
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{n\pi}\right)\sin nx$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\,\mathrm{u}\pars{x} & = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}
\,\hat{\mathrm{u}}_{n}\expo{\ic n x}\
\imp\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,\mathrm{u}\pars{x}\expo{-\ic nx}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi} =
\sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty}
\,\hat{\mathrm{u}}_{m}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{\ic\pars{m - n}x}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi} =
\,\hat{\mathrm{u}}_{n}
\\[4mm]
\,\hat{\mathrm{u}}_{n} & =
\half\,\delta_{n0} + \bracks{n \not= 0}\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{-\ic nx}
\,{\dd x \over 2\pi} =
\half + \bracks{n \not= 0}{\expo{-\ic n\pi} - 1 \over -2\pi\ic n}
\\[4mm] & =
\half\,\delta_{n0} - \bracks{n \not= 0}{\ic \over 2\pi}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n}
\end{align}

---

$$
\color{#f00}{\,\mathrm{u}\pars{x}} =
\color{#f00}{\half -{\ic \over \pi}
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\,{\expo{\ic\pars{2n + 1}x} \over 2n + 1}}
$$